# Why the :not() selector isn't working properly?

Tags: css, sass, less

I have a little problem with `:not()` not working properly. Here, the style is still applied despite the `:not(.no-dash)` selector:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="no-dash">
   <h2>Simple title</h2>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
div:not(.no-dash) {
   h2 ,h3, h4, h5, h6 {
      margin-bottom: 36px;

      &::after {
         content: "";
         display: block;
         position: absolute;
         bottom: -10px;
         left: 0;
         width: 45px;
         height: 3px;
         background-color: $color_yellow;
       }
    }
}
```

---

My real code:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="row mt-5">
   <div class="no-dash col-12 table-responsive">
      <h3>Simplifiez-vous le quotidien :</h3>
      <table class="table table-bordered mt-4">
         <thead>
            <tr class="text-center">
               <td class="alert-danger" style="width:50%">
                  <h4><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i> Un soucis ?</h4>
               </td>
               <td class="alert-info" style="width:50%">
                  <h4><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Une solution</h4>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>Vous avez oublié vos clés ?</td>
               <td>Nous avons le double !</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Votre ampoule a grillé ?</td>
               <td>Nous devons bien en avoir une d'avance !</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>La pile de votre souris est vide ?</td>
               <td>Nous devons bien en avoir une d'avance !</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Votre imprimante n'a plus d'encre ou est en panne ?</td>
               <td>Nous pouvons imprimer vos documents !</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="2">Etc., ...</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
:not(.no-dash) {
   h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
      &:not(.no-dash) {
         margin-bottom: 36px;

          &::after {
             content: "";
             display: block;
             position: absolute;
             bottom: -10px;
             left: 0;
             width: 45px;
             height: 3px;
             background-color: $color_yellow;
          }
      }

      &.text-center:not(.no-dash) {
         &::after {
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%);
         }
      }
    
      &.text-right:not(.no-dash) {
         &::after {
            left: auto;
            right: 0;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It works as expected check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/e7nu1tcs/2/).

Comment: Missing a closing `}` in the first example ?

Comment: Indeed "johannchopin" it works but why not for my. :(
Nop "anderssonola" all `}` are present.
I will post my real code.

Answer (score 0):

The `:not()` selector is not working here because your `h1`, `h2`, `h3`... are nested into multiple `div`, and not all of them have the excluded class. See for yourself:

```css
div:not(.no-dash) h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="no-dash">
        <h2>Nested in multiple div</h2>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div class="no-dash">
    <h2>Nested in a single div</h2>
</div>

<div>
    <h2>With no class</h2>
</div>
```

You can solve your problem by using the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) selector:

```css
div:not(.no-dash) > h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="no-dash">
        <h2>Nested in multiple div</h2>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div class="no-dash">
    <h2>Nested in a single div</h2>
</div>

<div>
    <h2>With no class</h2>
</div>
```

This will only work if the elements you wish to exclude are direct children of the `div` to which you are applying the excluded class.